# Xpage Error: Disk i/o is a restricted operation with Attachment

Tags: xpages, attachment

I am getting an error "Disk i/o is a restricted operation" when attaching a file and saving a xpage document using Internet Explorer.

Environment:
An xpage with richtext field and an upload control which is binded to the same richtext field (for saving attachments).

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Add the XPage signer to the field on the server document that identifies users who are allowed to run restricted operations. This field impacts permissions for both agents and XPages. So anything that would be considered a restricted operation in an agent will also be considered a restricted operation in an XPage, and the signer must be granted sufficient rights.